# Maximum Devastation to be caused if a building with height h causes all h-1 buildings to its right to collapse

Tags: algorithm

In a recent interview question I got the following problem.

In a particular city we have a row of buildings with varying heights.
The collapse of a building with height h causes the **next h-1 buildings on its right** to collapse too.
The height of the buildings can be between 1 and 5000. Given the heights of all the buildings (arranged from left to right ie; for leftmost building index=1 and for rightmost building index=N) we needed to find out the index of the building which would cause the maximum devastation.

For example:

Input:
Number of buildings : 6

Height of Buildings:
2 1 3 3 1 6

Answer should be building at the index 3

The solution I tried was using the brute force technique with a complexity of O(N^2).
What I did was for each building in the list I found out the number of buildings that it would destroy.

Could a better solution for this question be constructed?

Comment: Shouldn't the answer index 1? This would cause the next two buildings to collapse, and the second one (height 3) would cause the rest to collapse also. Also, what is "maximum devastation"? Is it the number of buildings that collapse, or their total height?

Comment: No. Please read the question. H-1 buildings collapse and not H.

Comment: @AnttiHuima if index is one, then only the 1st two buildings shall collapse.

Comment: Maximum devastation means number of buildings or sum of heights?

Comment: Maximum devastation means Number of buildings.
Height only plays a role in the fall of buildings.

Comment: @SilentPro so `next h-1 buildings on its right` doesn't refer to the right of the index of the building that collapses... but how does the height play a role in the fall? maybe the buildings should be sorted first?

Comment: It does refer to that. Say a building with height 2 at index 4 collapses.
In that case it would also cause the collapse of the building at index 5.

Comment: Hint: start from the rightmost building.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal did try to start from the rightmost as I thought it could be solved using some kind of dynamic programming approach but I couldn't pin it down to an algorithm.

Comment: The solution down below makes sense, but I'm still a bit foggy on why the correct answer is building at index 3. That is the first building with a height of 3, meaning that the building immediately to the right (also height 3) will not collapse because it is H and not H-1. The building at index 3 appears to have a maximum destruction of one building. From what it looks to me, building at index 1 and index 4 are tied for a maximum destruction of two buildings. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: The fall of a building does not depend on its height or the height of its previous building. A building falls if it is within h-1 buildings of a building that has fallen regardless of its height. For example 
3 6 1 10 1

The first building would lead to the fall of the second and third building among which the second building would lead to the fall of all the other buildings.

Comment: I'd need a _measure_ for `devastation`: #stories collapsed? #buildings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply go from the left, collapse the first building, and calculate how much total(*) damage it did.

Do this again and again from the very next building (which hasn't collapsed).

From these, pick the maximum.

Complexity: O(n).

This greedy algorithm works because the whole process is a chain reaction, if building A forces the collapse of B, then you cannot achieve better score starting from B.

(*) You can do this by maintaining one counter which stores how many buildings to the right should be collapsed.  `counter = max(counter - 1, height of next building)`.

Comment: WoW! seems very logical!

Answer (score 2):

some areas of the city function as "firewalls" - collapse stops at that point.  a little thought shows that these are sections to the left of a value of 1 where height increases (to the left) no more than once per step (if you can have 0 heights that complicates things very slightly).

and the highest scoring region must start just after a firewall (since if it didn't there would be a higher region just to the left).

so scan from the right, finding these firewalls, and then find which section to the right of a firewall has the largest damage.  this is O(n) because it's just linear scans (once from right to left and then once for each section, with no overlap).

actually, Karoly's answer is equivalent and simpler to implement.

Comment: I realized the exact thing that only a height of 1 can stop the collapse.
Could you please elaborate a little more.

Answer (score 1):

1. Start with rightmost index.
2. The last building shall cause a devastation value of 1.
3. Iterate leftwards.

Something like (devastation from building i)

```
D[i] = 1 + min( N-i, max( index[i]-1, 0+D[i+1],1+D[i+2],... to index[i]-1 terms ) )
```

Comment: What would be the complexity of this?

Comment: Unfortunately complexity seems not very far from O(N^2), will need to make it more efficient

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In Java, without considering subsequent collapses:</strike>

```
public static int collapse(int[] buildings) {
    int i, maxDamage, index, currentDamage;
    // do not consider the last building, it will cause only its own fall
    maxDamage = 1;
    index = buildings.length - 1;
    for(i = buildings.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // update maximum damage as the mimimum value between the building[i] (the height of the building at index i) and the remaining number of elements from i to the end of the array
        currentDamage = Math.min(buildings[i], buildings.length - i);
        System.out.println(currentDamage);
        if(currentDamage > maxDamage) {
            maxDamage = currentDamage;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

My final solution is different from the accepted one, which by the way I didn't fully understand.
The idea is to count starting from the rightmost position the number of buildings that the current index will collapse.

```
index:  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
height: 1  3  1  2  4  1  3  2
damage: 1  2  1  2  4  1  3  2
```

Then I just make a cumulative sum, starting from the rightmost position again. I add to the number of buildings the current position collapses the number of buildings that were collapsed staring from the next building to the right that didn't collapse until the end.

```
index:  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
height: 1  3  1  2  4  1  3  2
damage: 1  2  1  2  5  1  7  8
```

In the end, I just return the index with the maximum damage.

This solution runs in `O(n)` but uses an extra `O(n)` space.

The next code is the complete version (also works for subsequent collapses):

```
public static int collapse(int[] buildings) {
    int i, maxIndex, max;
    int damage[] = new int[buildings.length];
    for(i = buildings.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // compute damage for each position
        damage[i] = Math.min(buildings[i], buildings.length - i);
    }
    for(i = buildings.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // update total accumulated damage for each position
        if(damage[i] > 1) {
            if(damage[i] + i - 1 < buildings.length && i != (i + damage[i] - 1) ) {
                damage[i] += damage[i + damage[i] - 1] - 1;
            }
        }
    }
    max = damage[0];
    maxIndex = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < buildings.length; i++) {
        // find the maximum damage
        if(damage[i] > max) {
            max = damage[i];
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return maxIndex;
}
```

Comment: No, this does not take subsequent collapses into consideration. Say we have the array `[2,3,1,4,2,1,3,1]`, this will return 3 instead of 0, because collapsing of building #0 will cause #1 to collapse, which in turn will collapse #3, which in turn will collapse #6 resulting in total destruction.

Comment: I didn't consider subsequent collapses. So they apply?

Comment: Yes, they do. "Collapse causes collapse" mean reiterate "collapse" for next buildings.

Comment: `[1,3,1,2,4,3,1,2]` should result in 1 as an answer, and your data mining says 0. See, collapsing the building at #0 won't result in any subsequent collapses, thus the damage at [0] should be 1, your subsequent-damage calculator says 8.

Comment: Most likely it's because your damage calculation gives 1 for 1-story building, which is then interpreted as 1 subsequent collapse, while there are 0. You should fix this. Undownvoted though.

Answer (score 0):

Same approach as @Karoly's answer. In ruby:

```
def find_max_damage_index(buildings)

  max_damage = 0
  max_start_index = nil

  current_start_index = nil
  current_h = 0
  current_damage = 0

  buildings.each_with_index{|h,i|
    if current_h == 0 #end of batch
      if current_damage > max_damage
        max_damage = current_damage
        max_start_index = current_start_index
      end
      #start new batch
      current_h = h
      current_damage = 1
      current_start_index = i
    else
      current_h = h if h > current_h
      current_damage += 1
    end
    current_h -= 1
  }
  #last batch
  if current_damage > max_damage
    max_damage = current_damage
    max_start_index = current_start_index
  end

  return max_start_index
end
```

Comment: Thanks but I never wanted the implementation. I explicitly mentioned algorithm.